# WPF & Specflow & Coded UI Tests: Exception when using Examples without an application restart

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow

I am using Specflow and Coded UI Tests to check if input validation in a WPF application works as expected. I have a feature like the following:

```
@InputValidation
Feature: Foo

Scenario Outline: Bar
    Given I am in the input screen
    When <input> is entered into text box
    Then the text box has the status <status>

Examples: 
 | input   | status  |
 | ""      | invalid |
 | "0"     | invalid |
 | "42"    | valid   |
```

That works fine as long as I restart the application after each scenario block (AfterScenarioBlock("InputValidation")). Unfortunately this takes a lot of time during the nightly build because I have to start the whole application, do the input, check the status and close the application for each data set in the table.

My problem is that I get an exception ("The Coded UI Test is running in Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode of COM.  In this mode, all the playback calls should happen from the TestMethod thread only and UITestControl should not be shared across TestMethods.") when ever I try to use Examples without a restart.

The reason for this seems to be, that Specflow generates a new TestMethod for each row in the example table. These methods have all different threads and thus can not access the same UI Element.

I am not sure with this and thus wanted to ask if there is any other reason for this exception and if it is possible to use Examples without a restart or share UI elements between different test methods.

Comment: What kind of application are you testing against? I have done this thing against a web site (using the selenium web driver) without any issues many times.

Comment: I am testing a WPF application.

Comment: What do you mean by "*These methods have all different threads*"? I know nothing about Specflow or what it does. How are the Coded UI test methods being executed, are you using the normal Coded UI means or is Specflow doing something? Are you trying to run multiple tests methods at the same time in one computer?

Comment: I think a [TestMethod] inside a [CodedUiTest] class is executed each time in another thread than the other [TestMethod]s. I am not sure if this is realy the reason for the exception but it seems so.